# How to use a DLL in a Haskell project?

Tags: haskell, shared-libraries, ghc, cabal, haskell-stack

I would like to use an external library, [RDFox](http://www.cs.ox.ac.uk/isg/tools/RDFox/), in a Haskell project.

**Context:** I am working on Windows and Linux, both 64 bits, using GHC 7.10 and [stack](https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack). RDFox is programmed in C++. RDFox shared libraries (.dll, .so) can be downloaded with Java and Python wrappers.

**Aim:** I would like to reuse the compiled libraries from RDFox (.dll, .so) in my project in Haskell, so I need to create a Haskell wrapper for RDFox.

**Issues:** Being relatively new to Haskell, I have difficulty to know where to start. I found several pages about the subject (from the Haskell wiki and StackOverflow), but the workflow and configuration are not clear to me.

**Questions:** I would like to know:

> 1. How to configure stack and cabal to use external library, to build on Windows *or* Linux (different machines, same repository).
> 2. How to configure GHCi for interactive testing on this external library.
> 3. Is the translation of the Python wrapper to Haskell the best way to go? I would like to avoid the analysis of the RDFox C++ code.

Comment: First you probably need to create a C-exported wrapper for the C++ api.

Comment: Isn't is possible to directly create the wrapper in Haskell? I mean, if I have to create a C wrapper and then a Haskell one, what's the point?

Comment: Naming conventions in C++ are much more complicated than in C. I don't think FFI supports the name mangling for non-extern-C things.

Comment: If you know the name-mangling scheme you can use `System.Win32.DLL` from the `Win32` package and `System.Posix.DynamicLinker` from the `unix` package. However, the name-mangling will probably differ between the two platforms, so you have to do the work twice. If you write a C wrapper, you only have to do it once.

Comment: Just learn to love extern "C"{} in C++.

Comment: You don't need to create any C wrapper. Necessary `extern "C"` is already in place (one would have a hard time creating the Python wrapper without it).

Answer (score 2):

1. You'll need to use `extra-lib-dirs` and `extra-libraries` in the `executable` section of your `.cabal` file like so:

   ```
   name:                 MyApp
   version:              0.1.0.0
   synopsis:
   homepage:
   author:               simon.bourne
   category:
   build-type:           Simple
   cabal-version:        >=1.10

   library
     exposed-modules:      HelloWorld
     build-depends:        base >= 4.7 && < 5
     hs-source-dirs:       src
     default-language:     Haskell2010

   executable MyApp
     main-is:              Main.hs
     extra-lib-dirs:       lib
     extra-libraries:      helloWorld
     build-depends:        base >= 4.7 && < 5,
                           MyApp
     hs-source-dirs:       app

   default-language: Haskell2010
   ```

   Put your dll and .so in `lib`. Be warned, you'll run into link order problems if you use a static library (`.a` instead of `.so`) on linux.

   See [this](https://github.com/simon-bourne/HaskellFFILinkerProblem) for an example. Don't be fooled by the name as it works fine with `.so` files.
2. `stack ghci` should just work provided it can find your library (`LD_LIBRARY_PATH` on linux).
3. The C API (mentioned in the comments on your question) is already there. You just need to write the Haskell FFI signatures, for example:

   ```
   foreign import ccall safe "helloWorld" c_helloWorld :: IO ()
   ```

   I'd very strongly advise using `safe` ccalls, and don't wrap the functions in `unsafePerformIO`.

   If you need to pass non opaque structs, you might want to investigate `c2hs` or `hsc2hs`, but I don't think you'll need to. See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6009031/difference-between-hsc2hs-and-c2hs) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a C-exported wrapper for the C++ api and Haskell wrapper to FFI to C-exported wrapper.

Marshaling between C# and Haskell described here:
[Calling Haskell from C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16615641/calling-haskell-from-c-sharp)

but it very similar marshaling between C++ and Haskell

For example, create C++ export function:

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int __cdecl addFive(int number);

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int __cdecl addFive(int number)
{
    return number + 5;
}
```

In Haskell you need import code:

```
foreign import ccall "addFive" addFive :: Int -> Int
```

Then you can use addFive in Haskell as typical Haskell-function

For compbound data types (classes and structures) you need create C++ data-type analog in Haskell. Then you need describe how marshal data types from C++ to Haskell and from Haskell to C++.

In Haskell it means that you need create Storable instance for you data types.

Answer (score 0):

Answer from [this documentation](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.0.3/docs/html/users_guide/win32-dlls.html):

```
ghc -c Adder.hs
ghc -c StartEnd.c
ghc -shared -o Adder.dll Adder.o Adder_stub.o StartEnd.o
```

Comment: This is for exporting a haskell dll for use in other languages. OP's asking how to use a dll exported from C++ in a haskell program.